# Store HTML Checkboxes (array) into a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox, insert

I want to store basic user input into a database via INSERT INTO.
I've managed to store all input possible (text, tel...) but checkboxes is a problem as they are arrays! How can I store them?

**vos_jeux.php** (where checkboxes are displayed)

```
<form method="post" action="end.php">
  <p>
    Cochez les jeux désirés pour votre soirée:<br>

      <label for="blackjack"><img src="img/blackjack.jpg" alt=""></label>
      <INPUT id="blackjack" type="checkbox" name="game[]" value="Blackjack">    

      <label for="chuckaluck"><img src="img/chuckaluck.jpg" alt=""></label>
      <INPUT id="chuckaluck" type="checkbox" name="game[]" value="Chuck à Luck">

      <label for="roulette"><img src="img/roulette.jpg" alt=""></label>
      <INPUT id="roulette" type="checkbox" name="game[]" value="Roulette">

      <label for="stud"><img src="img/stud.jpg" alt=""></label>
      <INPUT id="stud" type="checkbox" name="game[]" value="Stud Poker">

      <label for="holdem"><img src="img/holdem.jpg" alt=""></label>
      <INPUT id="holdem" type="checkbox" name="game[]" value="Holdem Poker">

      <label for="boule"><img src="img/boule.jpg" alt=""></label>
      <INPUT id="boule" type="checkbox" name="game[]" value="La Boule">

    <input type="button" value="Retour en arrière" onClick="self.history.back();">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Poursuivre">
  </p>
</form>
```

Look at my database: (see how "jeux" checkboxes don't appear)
[image: PHPMyAdmin]

end.php

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$nom = $_POST['nom'];
$prenom = $_POST['prenom'];
$adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$adresse2 = $_POST['adresse2'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$nb_invite = $_POST['nb_invite'];
$evenement = $_POST['evenement'];
$game = implode(',', $_POST['game']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux)
VALUES ('$nom', '$prenom', '$adresse', '$tel', '$mail', '$adresse2', '$date', '$nb_invite', '$evenement', '$game')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

1_ I tried the "implode" solution but it doesn't seem to work. What can I do?
2_ Echoing the $sql variable gives: `INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux) VALUES ('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', '')`
The results of the checkbox inputs is **NULL** '' ! Why?

Comment: what is the output for var_dump($game) (add this right before the $sql statement). Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: where is `recap.php` ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 it gives me "NULL INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux) VALUES ('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', '')"

Comment: I don't think you are accessing the $_POST array correctly. There is no input for nom, prenom etc. since you are putting those values into a 2 dimensional numeric array.

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) at the start of end.php and see what you get.

Comment: @Maximus2012 Got that: array(10) { ["nom"]=> string(3) "foo" ["prenom"]=> string(3) "foo" ["adresse"]=> string(3) "foo" ["tel"]=> string(3) "foo" ["mail"]=> string(3) "foo" ["adresse2"]=> string(3) "foo" ["date"]=> string(3) "foo" ["nb_invite"]=> string(3) "foo" ["evenement"]=> string(3) "foo" ["game"]=> string(5) "Array" } INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux) VALUES ('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', '')

Comment: yea i would debug by first seeing if your form is actually sending the correct POST data to your php., if not, fix those errors, but if the correct data is sent, then you need to check your syntax, perhaps you have one too many spaces on your SQL query. maybe around the VALUES section.

Comment: in your Database, how is the `jeux` field defined? is it `TEXT`, `VARCHAR`, ....? This might be denying the insertion... and what do you get when you postdata `$game`, before your SQL

Comment: Try accessing the values like $_POST['game']['nom'] and so on and see if that works.

Comment: @CodeGodie Varchar(256). Is it good? It just display "Array"

Comment: change that to `TEXT` and try it

Comment: @CodeGodie No changes :/ No errors, it just act like it was "empty" variables

Comment: did that work? or is it still giving you errors? if so, what errors?

Comment: what do you see when you var_dump `$game` after the `implode`?

Comment: this one seems to be your HTML somehow

Comment: its working for me here locally. something seems to be wrong with your local setup. what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Next time, **post your real form code**, most especially the hidden input which was just that, **hidden/not shown**. You've wasted a lot of people's time.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

```
<?php
    // Get array
    $games = $_POST['game'];

foreach ($games as $game)
        {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux)
VALUES ('$nom', '$prenom', '$adresse', '$tel', '$mail', '$adresse2', '$date', '$nb_invite', '$evenement', '$game')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
        }

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but sorry it doesn't seem to work. When I arrive at end.php it just display "NULL"

Comment: I assume it's for the $game one, since every other stores w/o problem in the db

Comment: @cheezburger, $game will not be null bro..i am sure about it..i tested it here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to check your database fields' type, specifically the `jeux` field, make sure you have that set to `TEXT` or `LONGTEXT` if you have large amount of data to be stored... If this is not the problem, check that you dont have random spaces especially around your SQL query, maybe around the VALUES area.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the "jeux" type field is correctly set to TEXTHere the vardump: array(10) { ["nom"]=> string(3) "foo" ["prenom"]=> string(3) "foo" ["adresse"]=> string(3) "foo" ["tel"]=> string(3) "foo" ["mail"]=> string(3) "foo" ["adresse2"]=> string(3) "foo" ["date"]=> string(3) "foo" ["nb_invite"]=> string(3) "foo" ["evenement"]=> string(3) "foo" ["game"]=> string(5) "Array" } NULL INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux) VALUES ('foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo', '')

Comment: and Im assuming you dont want to store `$games` as an array correct? what happens when you try to store it without the `implode`?

Comment: Not really. I just want data to be present in my database because afterwards I will need it. I try what you said but in PHPMyAdmin, it just display "Array": http://i.imgur.com/8AAuv0t.png

Comment: can you provide the var_dump results of `$_POST['game']` ?

Comment: so thats, good... what about the var_dump result of `$game` (after the implode)?

Comment: so your problem is your HTML form.. somehow youre not getting the data youre selecting

Comment: Do you see any flaws in my HTML form?

Comment: i guess you cant chat yet.. man i wanted to help you remotely... your HTML looks good

Comment: Yep. I need 20 reputation, can you upvote my question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71040/discussion-between-codegodie-and-cheezburger).

Comment: I hope I was able to help finding that problem.

Answer (score -1):

Use a foreach to create/concat a $game string:

```
$game = "";
foreach($_POST['game'] as $g){
$game .= $g.", ";
}
```

And then you can use the $game string in you sql query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO donnees (nom, prenom, adresse, tel, email, adresse2, date, nb_invite, evenement, jeux)
VALUES ('$nom', '$prenom', '$adresse', '$tel', '$mail', '$adresse2', '$date', '$nb_invite', '$evenement', '$game')";
```

Comment: Doesn't store nothing in the db, sorry!

Comment: try to remove those asterisks from the sql ** ('**$game'**)... i wanted to bold the code, but stack overflow html editor change the code and you probably got and sql syntax error :-(